# Login function not working, header function broken?

Tags: php, login-script

Here's the deal, my function stopped working all of the sudden, probably due to the hosting changing something, I honestly don't know why but only on this *login.php* the header function doesn't work at all, and all used to work perfectly, and I was logging in, out, doing sessions etc.

```
<?php 
        if($_SESSION['username']){

        header('Location: http://xshooter.hol.es/index.php');
        exit();
        }

        if($_POST['submittedLogin']==1){

            $pass=md5($_POST['loginPassword']);
            $db=Mysql_connect ("mysql.hostinger.hr","u386117026_admin","");
            mysql_select_db ("u386117026_db");

            $sql="SELECT * FROM u386117026_db.user WHERE username='" . $_POST['loginUsername'] . "' AND password='" . $pass . "'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            if($result){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            if(($row['username']==$_POST['loginUsername'])&&($row['password']==$pass)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['loginUsername'];
            $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['admin']=$row['admin'];


            header("Location: http://xshooter.hol.es/index.php");
            exit();
            }else{

            header("Location: http://xshooter.hol.es/index.php?loginfail=1");
            exit;
            }
            }

            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: where is `session_start();`? Add `session_start();` on next line after your `<?php`

Comment: I tryed that out already, didn't make any diffwerence...

Answer (score -1):

Please add:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

after php open tag (2nd line), and paste the output here.